# Kitchen light switch controlling master bedroom power

Tags: electrical

I had a handyman out here to open up/widen the doorway into the kitchen. As part of that job he had to relocate some switches and plugs over a couple inches. Now my kitchen light switch controls the lights in my master bedroom. Or, put differently, my master bedroom lights will NOT turn on unless the kitchen light switch is also on.

Attached is a photo of the kitchen light switch and the box that he told me he “housed the new connections” in. Any help?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did the handyman have an electrical license from your LAHJ? Generally speaking, if the answer to that is, as expected, no, then they should not be doing wiring for pay unless it is under the direct supervision and direction of you the homeowner, or a licensed electrician. If you the homeowner are not sufficiently knowledgeable to supervise and direct their electrical work, you need someone who is actually qualified, not some random unqualified person, at least in any civilized location with an electrical code.

Comment: Poor screw connections. Two wires under one screw. And old wires (I am familiar with those, unfortunately) which makes working on things a little harder. This could be as simple as one wire of the two wires that are under one screw needing to be connected (but with a wire nut and pigtail, not under the screw) to the other screw. But it could be much, much more.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Usually the solution to this is "dude, the kitchen light is controlling the bedroom lights, you need to fix this."  But in this case it would probably be best if this person didn't touch any more electrical components.

Comment: *Handyman*: "I got this stuff wired up for you"; *electrician*: "OK cool, I will go ahead and redo it all correctly then, thanks."

Answer (score 2):

Aside from a non licensed person doing electrical work and the poor work at that, this is most likely an issue of incorrect wire placement.

On the switch, the 2 top wires are probably to your bedroom lights and to the kitchen light.  The bottom wire is hot.

You need to find which of the top wires control your bedroom lights and pigtail it to the bottom  wire.  This will restore power to your bedroom lights.

The remaining top wire just need to be properly bent around the screw and tightened properly.  The pigtailed bottom wires get the same on the bottom screw.
Of course work carefully with the breaker to the circuit off. Turning it on just to check your work and find the bedroom wire.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add here that the box in the second photo violates the recessed mounting limit, isn't grounded correctly, and doesn't even look safe to me.

It might be worth bringing in an electrician to get this done to code.  What you have now is obviously less than a workmanlike result.